# Decrypt crypt7 without key (phone was factory reset)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, encryption

I have my whatsapp backup db in crypt7 format. I forgot to backup the crypt key.

Now I want to decrypt the crypt7 file but not sure what to do. I have my device with me on which the file was encrypted, but the device has been factory reset, hence I am unable to get the key from it.

Now my question is, if I reinstall whatsapp, will I be able to get the crypt key and will I be able to decrypt the file which was encrypted before factory reset?

if not, is there any other possible way to decrypt it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the whatsapp crypt7 files are not actually encrypted.

There is an [app that can encrypt/decrypt/backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.omnicrypt) the crypt7 files without a key.

Also, over copy-pasting your whatsapp folder will also work, i think i've succesfully tried that already...